# php setting array index to value of an ID

Tags: php, json, object, multidimensional-array

I am having an issue where I am trying to save an `ID` as an array index, but when I convert the array to json, the `ID` is appearing as an object and not as an array element.

This is a brief example:

```php
    $ID = 1001 ;
    $item = [] ;
    $item["regional"] = [] ;
    $item["regional"][$ID] = $someInfo ; //object
    json_encode($item) ;
```

I am returning the json to my app, and when I look at the json formatting the above lists `1001` as an object:

```php
     [0: 
         { regional:
              { 1001 :
                   someInfoA : valueA
                   someInfoB : valueB
              }
         }
    ]
```

If I change the value of `$ID = 0`, then it stores the `ID` as a proper array index - which is what I am needing:

```php
    $ID = 0 ;
    $item = [] ;
    $item["regional"] = [] ;
    $item["regional"][$ID] = $someInfo ; //object
    json_encode($item) ;
```

The above now shows `ID = 0` as an array index [0]:

```php
     [0: 
         { regional:
              [ 0 :
                   {
                   someInfoA : valueA
                   someInfoB : valueB
                   }
              ]
         }
    ]
```

How can I get the first example to set the array index as `1001` and be treated as an array element versus as an object.  I am needing to do this so I can quickly see if that array index element/ID exists to either add to it, or create it then add to it.

If this can't be done, then how can I search a multi-dimensional array/object to return the array index that contains the object value `1001` ?

```php
     [0: 
         { regional:
              [ 0 :
                   {
                   ID: 1000
                   someInfoA : valueA
                   someInfoB : valueB
                   }
              ]
              [ 1 :
                   {
                   ID: 1001
                   someInfoA : valueA
                   someInfoB : valueB
                   }
              ]
         }
    ] 

$index = array_key_exists($item["regional"],1001) ;  // or something like this
var_dump($index) ; // index = 1 ;
```

Comment: JavaScript does not know “associative” arrays - there is not other way than an object, if you want keys like that.

Comment: _“I am needing to do this so I can quickly see if that array index element/ID exists”_ - so check if the _object_ has a _property_ by that name then.

Comment: @04FS Ok, as I thought.  But that is my last question, if I can't do what I was trying, then how (in PHP) can I extract the index that the `ID:1001` belongs to without doing a foreach loop.

Comment: You can json_decode it as an array using `true` as second arg.  Also, look at array_column, works on objects also in 7+

Comment: Its not fully clear what your are trying to do, but, as said above you are probably looking for the second argument (to true) in json_decode, or you can try to convert to an array using the `(array) $item["regional"]` syntax, and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php may be part of your answer